# numpy.linalg.lstsq equivalent in Apache Commons Math Java library?

Tags: java, python, math, scipy, apache-commons

I have the following call to numpy.linalg.lstsq:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

x = [[ 0.69314718]
 [ 1.09861229]
 [ 1.38629436]
 [ 1.60943791]
 [ 1.79175947]
 [ 1.94591015]]

y = [ 0. 0.20273255  0.5815754   0.7520387   0.96885669 1.09861229]

l = numpy.linalg.lstsq(x, y)

which returns

l -> tuple: (array([ 0.46323573]), array([ 0.25872885]), 1, array([ 3.63269497]))

Could somebody point out the equivalent function (if available) in

http://commons.apache.org/math/

(or possibly in some other Java math library ...)

Comment: I'm not even remotely a java person, but quickly browsing the docs would seem to indicate that you want this: http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/math/linear/DecompositionSolver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the pointer Joe.

Here is the code for reference:

```
double[][] testSquare = {{0.69314718}, {1.09861229}, {1.38629436}, {1.60943791}, {1.79175947}, {1.94591015}};
RealMatrix matrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(testSquare);
SingularValueDecomposition svd = new SingularValueDecomposition(matrix);
DecompositionSolver ds=svd.getSolver();
double[] b = {0.0, 0.20273255, 0.5815754, 0.7520387, 0.96885669, 1.09861229};
ds.solve(b)[0];
```

Comment: This is outdated, etc., `SingularValueDecompositionImpl` does not exist anymore.